# Adding Django to already made HTML/css site

Tags: html, django

Hey guys so I been looking into making a site and was going to learn php for it but after a lot of research I saw how I can use Django for the backend of the site so I already started creating a site with HTML/css/js before I decide to use Django. Is there any possible way you can connect HTML/css to Django or do I need to re write everything in Django. I did look at some tutorials and saw how all the HTML was in django and I also did try looking it up too but couldn't find the right answer I'm looking for. If anyone could tell me I'll be very appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: All you have to do is copy html file to django project folder.If you want to pass data to html from backend you will have to write appropriate veiw and send context to the html.Go through django official tutorial(atleast first 4 parts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect it. Django is a backend framework, all it does in the frontend is print data.

Read about [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/) in Django. Templates are basically html files with dynamic content.

Take the template **my_template.html**:

```
My first name is {{ first_name }}.
```

You render it like this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', {'first_name': 'Cesar'})
```

It will output:

```
My first name is Cesar.
```

Make sure to read the whole [intro tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) to Django.

Note: There are many ways to use a template, this was just a little example.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to move from your old project to new one created with django-admin startproject are:

1. HTML templates adapted to django template language configured as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/
2. css/img/js files to static folder

After it you need to replace old href attributes to something like `<a href="{% url "Index" %}">` and insert correct paths (includes static url) of css/img/js files to hmtl